# OpenEmbedded Toolchain with Newer GCC

Tags: gcc, toolchain, cross-compiling, openembedded

I want to build a cross-compile toolchain using OpenEmbedded that has either gcc version 4.6 or linaro gcc instead of the gcc version 4.5 that comes by default. Is this possible? I think I should only need to make a few changes in the local.conf file, but I'm having trouble figuring out what. To be clear, I'm using OE classic instead of OE-core.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would set the following in your configuration:

```
PREFERRED_GCC_VERSION ?= "4.6"
```

There is no recipe for GCC 4.6 in oe-dev though. oe-core comes with GCC 4.7.

You may find the following page interesting also:

https://wiki.linaro.org/KenWerner/Sandbox/OpenEmbedded-Core